# How do you signal you want to reference an assemby with manos de mono server?

Tags: c#, mono, dmcs, manos

Using dmcs directly, if I want to reference an assembly I can pass it in via the -r option, ala:

dmcs -r:System.Xml.Linq.dll whatever.cs

manos de mono uses its own build system on top of dmcs, how do I pass in such references?  Seems like it should be easy/obvious but I haven't found any documentation on it so I'm asking here prior to ripping through the manos code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Manos automatically references all .dlls found in the directory the .cs files are (unless you use .sln or makefile, that is).

Secondly, I don't think additional reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll is needed, AFAIR it should be visible to `manos -b` thanks to correct mono installation present "in the OS" -- so if the example reflects what you're doing literally, I would suspect the problem lies somewhere outside Manos build system. I may be right or wrong saying the latter, but either way, given no further details I'd say both:

- repairing the "external" problem, or
- copying `System.Xml.Linq.dll` to the build directory

should help, and copying is definitely less cumbersome on the short term ;)